# Split screen divider stuck on Desktop, not actually dividing any windows, distracting - how to remove?

Tags: macos, mojave, desktop, split-view

How can the split screen divider be removed, please?

When not using a Desktop workspace/area, I can see the vertical divider over the Desktop, but this isn't serving any purpose and is therefore distracting.

See screenshot:

[image: id]

MacBook Air 11" 2015, 1366 x 768 screen, 8Gb RAM, 2.2 Ghz i7, 500Gb SSD, macOS mojave 10.14.2

Additional screenshots:

Notifications pop-up goes over the split divider (Answering question in comments from @bmike )

[image]

On opening e.g. Chrome, this goes on top of the divider, but the divider can then be dragged over the window as shown.

[image]

Comment: Couple of side questions that may not be relevant. When you click the Today/Notificiations icon (three horizontal lines - top right of menu bar) does that move over or affect the split? How many spaces exist in Mission Control? If you go to the log in window, how many other users are logged in and does the split resume when you arrive back? If you choose log out, do you save apps and does changing that and logging out / in help? (basically I know this has gotten corrupt for you - trying to figure where the corruption is and what resets it)

Comment: 1) notifications move over split 2) 9 spaces in mission control 3)  1 user logged in 4) split resumes when arrive back 5) no, don't save apps, close them. Thanks for your troubleshooting so far...

Comment: Ugh - so it's going to be the finder saved application state / window server.

Answer (score 1):

It may be an old question, but the same problem still bugs me today  on macos Monterey 12.4 on a Mac mini (M1, 2020) with 2 external displays.

It happens when I have multiple desktops with split screen apps. At some point the black divider disappears on one of the desktops and appears on another unrelated Desktop and just stay there - in the middle of the screen.

Luckily I found a simple fix for this problem by restarting the window server.

It does not cause any data loss or anything else. The windows/desktops will flicker for a second and then return to its previous state with all black bars gone or back where they actually belong.

Just run this command in a terminal:

```
killall -KILL Dock
```

Comment: +1 thank you for your solution. I've not seen the issue myself since, but pleased that the question and answers here are still valuable.

Comment: Same issue on MacOS Monterey, M1 macbook pro. The command does not help in my case

Comment: Fixed it by undoing any other split screens that were there. Undoing one of the split screen desktops should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue on MacOS Monterey, M1 macbook pro. The `killall -KILL Dock` command does not help in my case.
Fixed it by undoing any other split screens that were there. Undoing one of the split screen desktops fixes it.